# Moving Oracle objects between schemas (unicity constraints restrictions)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, tablespace, data-transfer-objects

Actually on **Oracle 10g**.
We could migrate to **12c** if this can help us out.

- We 2 *schemas* : **A_ADMIN** and **A2**.
- Main *schema* is **A2** which contains some *synonyms* pointing to **A_ADMIN** *tables*.
- We'd like to move referenced **A_ADMIN** *objects* to **A2** *schema* so only one *schema* would be needed.
- There are *triggers, packages, indexes, unicity constraints*...

What's the best way to proceed, considering we have development and production environment so **we'd like to prepare migration script(s)** to do so ?

Comment: A tablespace does not have schemas, there is no direct relationship between the two.  Schemas may store objects in many tablespaces, tablespaces may have objects from multiple tablespaces.  How much data are we talking about?  The simplest option (though not the most efficient) would probably be to export and import the data while changing the schema owner.

Comment: Thank you Justin for this clarification, I'm no DBA at all as you can see... Confusion must come from the fact I noticed a tablespace is a true file (OS filesystem) where my schema seems to be stored in...
I already tried this but it seems I have to refine my procedure since there are too many conflicts (unicity constraints as far as I know).
I'll try to go further and refine my question...

Comment: @JustinCave - I suspect you meant "...tablespaces may have objects from multiple **schemas**".

Comment: @BobJarvis - Quite right, yes.